# É possível configurar o display errors no .htaccess?

Tags: php, htaccess

Nas informações sobre meu serviço de hospedagem, tem uma linha que informa que não posso alterar o `php.ini`, mas que posso mudar a maioria das configurações através do `.htaccess`. Gostaria de habilitar os erros através do `.htaccess` se possivel, e só desabilitar os *Notices*. Isso é possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível desde que o ambiente (servidor) permita o acesso a tais configurações.

Não há muito o que dizer sobre o que funciona ou não pois quem poderá responder é o suporte do serviço de hospedagem.

Normalmente pode habilitar ou desabiltar usando php_flag

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

Faça isso no htaccess e veja o que acontece. Normalmente quando não é permitido retorna um "internal error", "error 500" e coisas do tipo.

Alternativamente, verifique se o provedor de hospedagem suporta php.ini customizado. Hosts mais modernos oferecem por padrão. No entanto, é tudo bem restritivo, especialmente se for host compartilhado.

Uma sugestão é configurar o log de erros ao invés do `display_error` como `ON`.

O padrão do ambiente de produção é sempre `OFF` pois ajuda a proteger o site em geral de expor informações sensíveis quando há algum erro.